# Number of calls to determine size of stack/queue

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Question 1**

You have an abstract stack with *n* entries and an empty abstract queue (to help). Approximately how many calls are needed to determine *n*? The stack needs to be unchanged afterwards.

**Question 2**

Same question, but you start with an abstrack queue and have an empty abstrack stack.

**My reasoning**

Pop from stack -> push onto queue -> get from queue -> put on stack -> pop from stack -> push onto queue -> get from queue -> put on stack. Somewhere we throw in a counter and that makes it 8*n calls (9*n if the counter calls count). I don't see how else I can pop the items from the stack and then get them back in the right order. **Is there a better way?**

Answer (score 0):

Q1. A better solution could be:

1. pop
2. enqueue
3. dequeue
4. push

By do this, you get 4*n operations.

For instance, let be stack:  1, 2, 3 (with 1 as the top)

Let be s the stack and q the queue.

q.enqueue(s.pop()), so now s = [2, 3] and q = [1]

q.enqueue(s.pop()), so now s = [3] and q = [1, 2]

q.enqueue(s.pop()), so now s = [] and q = [1, 2, 3]

s.push(q.dequeue()), so now s = [1] and q = [2, 3]

s.push(q.dequeue()), so now s = [2, 1] and q = [3]

s.push(q.dequeue()), so now s = [3, 2, 1] and q = []

q.enqueue(s.pop()), so now s = [2, 1] and q = [3]

q.enqueue(s.pop()), so now s = [1] and q = [3, 2]

q.enqueue(s.pop()), so now s = [] and q = [3, 2, 1]

s.push(q.dequeue()), so now s = [3] and q = [2, 1]

s.push(q.dequeue()), so now s = [2, 3] and q = [1]

s.push(q.dequeue()), so now s = [1, 2, 3] and q = []

I don't think this could be the best solution, but is a better solution (9*n vs 4*n, always O(n))

Q2. I think that the same (not optimal) algorithm of previous case could be used now...

The main idea is that when you get an item from stack, this would be the last of the queue, cause the two data stuctures have a different way for input.

Hope this helps you :-)

Comment: I think that this answer does not change anything in the number of call. the approach il also the same.